# build.xml expects tools.jar at a different location

Tags: ant, java

While using Ant to build my application, the build is successful but at the beginning it says

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in
>   D:\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
>
> However my tools.jar is at the location D:\Java\jdk6u30\lib

I understand that tools.jar contains classes needed by jdk and should only be present at jdk lib and nowhere else. I hope I am correct on this.
My question is that why does build.xml expects it at a different location? I have my **JAVA_HOME**
set to

> D:\Java\jdk6u30

.

Comment: Do you developed the application in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So by default eclipse will take the jre as **installed JRE's** when you add the server. Change the **installed JRE's** to jdk.

You can locate it from **Window->Preferences->Java->installed JRE's**

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting this error when I execute some other command such as "deploywar" "D:\Workspace\Programs\ctcenterprise\build.xml:45: Unable to find a javac compile
r;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "D:\Java\jre6". My JAVA_HOME is not set to the one it is taking. Also in my eclipse the path is correctly set.

Comment: so you are saying that you set the JAVA_HOME to D:\Java\jre6 you should change the JAVA_HOME to jdk6. I mean the location you installed jdk6

Comment: I mean my JAVA_HOME was previously set to  D:\Java\jre6 and later I changed it to D:\Java\jdk6u30 as my jdk is installed here. Also I changed it in eclipse as well. But still when I build the app using ANT it is pointing to the old location only. Why this behavior?

Comment: Hey restarting everything helped. Thank you very much. The error is gone.